# Set a value to one cell using VBA worksheet change events. The value defined to one cell has to come from another cell

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I want to set a certain cell value to the value of another cell, when this cell value is filled in I want it to fill in the cell underneath without changing the cell previously filled. Say for instance I want to track numbers each day, for each day the end number will be applied to a weekly sum where each number from each day is shown. So Monday has 30, Tuesday has 50, and so forth. So say on Monday I get the value 30 from the tracker cell, then I want this value to automatically fill into the Monday cell of the week tracker. The next day I want to use the same-day tracker, but this time it fills in for Tuesday and so forth. I am a total beginner in VBA so I do not know how to get this to work. I have tried my best but can't achieve what I am looking for.

I will add a picture of what I mean, and how I want it, help would be awesome :-)
[image: The red arrows shows which value I want to add to the specified cells, they are in this instance F22 and F23, value has to be extracted from F14]

My code so far looks like this, not the best, but tried my best to pseudo-code what I thought could be the solution.

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(target, Range("F14")) Is Nothing Then
        If Not Intersect(target, Range("F22:F26")) Is Nothing Then
            If Range("F22") = 0 Then
                Range("F22").Value = Range("F14").Value //tried this first
            End If
            If target.Address = "$F$23" = 0 And target.Address = "$F$22" >= 0 Then
                SetCellValue target.Value = "$F$14"  //my second solution
            End If
            If target.Address = "$F$24" = 0 And target.Address = "F22:F23" >= 0 Then
                SetCellValue target.Value = "$F$14"
            End If
            If target.Address = "$F$25" = 0 And target.Address = "F22:F24" >= 0 Then
                SetCellValue target.Value = "$F$14"
            End If
            If target.Address = "$F$26" = 0 And target.Address = "F22:F25" >= 0 Then
                SetCellValue target.Value = "$F$14"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I can't get any value to show in the target cells, when F14 is changed, which I can't understand to be honest.

Comment: Does F14 hold as formula (eg `=SUM(F9:O9)` )?

Answer (score 0):

The change-event is triggered when a cell value is changed by the user (or by VBA code). So if you enter a value in one of the cells of the "Antall Poeng" - rows (I guess that's row 9), the trigger is called.

However, it is *not* called for a value that changes because it holds a formula and a recalculation of the formula returned a new value. I assume that F14 holds a formula like '=SUM(F9:O9)', so in the change-event, you could check if any of those cells was changed. However, the value of F14 is *not* calculated at this moment, so you would need to do the calculation by yourself.

The alternative is to use the `Worksheet_Calculate()`-Event that is fired every time Excel recalculates the sheet. This would copy the cell value any time something changes.

Now the only thing left is to figure out the row where you want to copy the value to. As this is weekday-dependent, you can use the `Weekday`-function.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim destCell As Range
    ' Weekday(Date, vbMonday) returns 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday...
    Set destCell = Range("F22").Offset(Weekday(Date, vbMonday) - 1)
    destCell.Value = Range("F14").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: thx for the solution, however I am not sure how to use the weekday code. could you give me an example

Comment: Geting an error saying, object required, tried typing
``` Weekday (Date, vbMonday) = vbFriday```

Comment: Just use the code I wrote.  You start at Range("F22") and calculate a (row) offset. `Weekday(Date, vbMonday)` will return the weekday of the current date, Monday=1, Tuesday=2... So for Monday, offset will be 0, for Tuesday, offset = 1, for Friday = 4.

Comment: I have tried, but I am just getting a runtime error, my code looks like this.
`Private Sub worksheet_calculate()
    Dim destCell As Range
    Weekday(23.01.2023, vbMonday)
    Set destCell = Range("F22").Offset(Weekday(Date, vbMonday) - 1)
    destCell.Value = Range("f14").Value
End Sub
`